# Perfmon and trustedinstaller working on boot on Win7, small 16 pixel window?

Tags: windows-7, security

I booted up my Windows 7 system, which is a nearly fresh install. I've only installed Chrome and Citrix reciever on there. However, it seemed to be going very slowly for about 5 or 10 minutes, and when I openned up the Resource Monitor, I saw that my cpu and disk were both running at 100% for extended periods, despite me not running anything. System interupts, perfmon, trusted installer, and chrome were all at the top of the list for percentage of CPU consumption.

Should I be concerned?

Edit. I just was looking at what looked like a 4-16 pixel square that was kind of like a stuck white pixel on top of everything. I clicked on it, and Windows focused on it, then I hit alt-f4 and it disappeared. I'm more of a linux person. What logs should I be checking for this?

Answer (score 1):

Trusted Installer is the engine which is used by Windows Update to scan for updates and install them. So on a fresh Windows 7, Windows Update takes some time to scan which updates it needs. This can take some time.